# Restrict Swagger UI access - user login

Tags: rest, authentication, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger UI for interactive REST endpoints representation. However, Swagger UI can be accessed by everyone who knows its URL. Is there any standard way to restrict Swagger UI access with user login?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using nginx you could add basic HTTP Authentication. Then anytime anyone goes to your docs url or sub-domain they'll get a pop-up user/password dialog before being able to access swagger-ui.

[Full instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10) for creating your user/password combinations (assuming Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd exampleuser
```

The tool will prompt you for a password.

Then update your nginx file to have something like this for the docs route:

```
location /docs {
   auth_basic "Restricted Content";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
   proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
 }
```

Then reload nginx:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Comment: Also you can restrict Swagger location by specific IP: allow 1.2.3.4; deny all;

Answer (score 1):

If you're afraid of unauthorized access, why not secure the API itself? I don't know if you can do what you asked, but even if you could, your API would still be accessible/vulnerable through `SOAP UI`, or `POSTMAN`, or just simple requests towards said URL.